# How to smooth verticies without subdivision modifier?

Tags: modeling, smooth

I want to smooth verticies to create the cleavage of jacket. I thought I can just delete some verticies, but the result is very bad:

[image]

How can I smooth this geometry? I can't just give subdiv modifier again and again in my attempts. I have this variant (just in case I broke everything in first screenshot):
[image]

Result I want to get:
[image]

Comment: I guess the best is to use the second mesh   ;)

Comment: @moonboots How and why? I just can't figure out how it will help.

Comment: what is the problem with your second topology exactly, is it too narrow? I'm not sure to understand...

Comment: Use a "smooth" operation or modifier.  Probably.

Comment: @moonboots well, it has very sharp edges in cleavage. I've added result I want to get.

Comment: @Nathan I've tried. Doesn't work at all. Don't know why.

Comment: What you show doesn't look like your cloth shape at all, you should rather redo it from scratch, the topology should follow the shape (so it should follow a V shape)